# @specialized + inner classes not allowed in scala?

Tags: scala, specialized-annotation

When I compile the following:

```
import org.junit.Test

class TypesTest{

  @Test
  def specializedTest(): Unit = {

    trait TTBase[@specialized T] {
      def evaluate:T
    }

    case class TTX[@specialized T](value:T) extends TTBase[T] {
      def evaluate:T = value
    }

    println( TTX(123).evaluate )
    println( TTX("s").evaluate )
  }
}
```

Then scala burps up the following error.

If TTBase and TTX are moved to the package scope, it compiles fine.
Is specialized not allowed in inner classes in scala (2.11)?

```
Error:scalac:
EmptyScope.enter
while compiling: /home/builder/aaa/lll/featureSystem/src/test/scala/com/ppp/scratch/TypesTest.scala
during phase: globalPhase=specialize, enteringPhase=explicitouter
library version: version 2.11.8
compiler version: version 2.11.8
reconstructed args: -nobootcp -javabootclasspath : -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/builder/aaa/lll/featureSystem/target/test-classes:/home/builder/aaa/lll/featureSystem/target/classes:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-graphdb/2.2.5/orientdb-graphdb-2.2.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-server/2.2.5/orientdb-server-2.2.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-client/2.2.5/orientdb-client-2.2.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.7/mail-1.4.7.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-tools/2.2.5/orientdb-tools-2.2.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-core/2.2.5/orientdb-core-2.2.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.0.1/snappy-java-1.1.0.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4.1/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blueprints-core/2.6.0/blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.3.3/jettison-1.3.3.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/hppc/0.6.0/hppc-0.6.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.1.0/javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/stuz5000/Soriento/b81fdebff6/Soriento-b81fdebff6.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scalap/2.11.8/scalap-2.11.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.8/scala-compiler-2.11.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.4/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.4.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-mllib_2.11/1.6.1/spark-mllib_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/1.6.1/spark-core_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.7.7/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-ipc/1.7.7/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.7/avro-1.7.7.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-ipc/1.7.7/avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill_2.11/0.5.0/chill_2.11-0.5.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.21/kryo-2.21.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/reflectasm/reflectasm/1.07/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.2/objenesis-1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.5.0/chill-java-0.5.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-asm5-shaded/4.4/xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.2.0/hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.1/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.2.0/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.2.0/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2/1.9/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-core/1.9/jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.9/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-grizzly2/1.9/jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http/2.1.2/grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-framework/2.1.2/grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/gmbal/gmbal-api-only/3.0.0-b023/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/external/management-api/3.0.0-b012/management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http-server/2.1.2/grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-rcm/2.1.2/grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http-servlet/2.1.2/grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.servlet/3.1/javax.servlet-3.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.9/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.8.3/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.8.3/jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-guice/1.9/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-common/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.2.0/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-launcher_2.11/1.6.1/spark-launcher_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-network-common_2.11/1.6.1/spark-network-common_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-network-shuffle_2.11/1.6.1/spark-network-shuffle_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/1.8/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-unsafe_2.11/1.6.1/spark-unsafe_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.7.1/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.4.0/curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.4.0/curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.4.0/curator-client-2.4.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.10/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.10/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/ning/compress-lzf/1.0.3/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/net/jpountz/lz4/lz4/1.3.0/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/roaringbitmap/RoaringBitmap/0.5.11/RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/2.2/commons-net-2.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.11/2.3.11/akka-remote_2.11-2.3.11.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.11/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.2.1/config-1.2.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.8.0.Final/netty-3.8.0.Final.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/uncommons/maths/uncommons-maths/1.2.2a/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-slf4j_2.11/2.3.11/akka-slf4j_2.11-2.3.11.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-jackson_2.11/3.2.10/json4s-jackson_2.11-3.2.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-core_2.11/3.2.10/json4s-core_2.11-3.2.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-ast_2.11/3.2.10/json4s-ast_2.11-3.2.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.9/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/mesos/mesos/0.21.1/mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.29.Final/netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/2.7.0/stream-2.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.1.2/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-jvm/3.1.2/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-json/3.1.2/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-graphite/3.1.2/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-client/0.8.2/tachyon-client-0.8.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-hdfs/0.8.2/tachyon-underfs-hdfs-0.8.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-s3/0.8.2/tachyon-underfs-s3-0.8.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-local/0.8.2/tachyon-underfs-local-0.8.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/net/razorvine/pyrolite/4.9/pyrolite-4.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.9/py4j-0.9.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming_2.11/1.6.1/spark-streaming_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.11/1.6.1/spark-sql_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-catalyst_2.11/1.6.1/spark-catalyst_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/janino/janino/2.7.8/janino-2.7.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/janino/commons-compiler/2.7.8/commons-compiler-2.7.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-column/1.7.0/parquet-column-1.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-common/1.7.0/parquet-common-1.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-encoding/1.7.0/parquet-encoding-1.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-generator/1.7.0/parquet-generator-1.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-hadoop/1.7.0/parquet-hadoop-1.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-format/2.3.0-incubating/parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-jackson/1.7.0/parquet-jackson-1.7.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-graphx_2.11/1.6.1/spark-graphx_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/core/1.1.2/core-1.1.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/f2j/arpack_combined_all/0.1/arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scalanlp/breeze_2.11/0.11.2/breeze_2.11-0.11.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scalanlp/breeze-macros_2.11/0.11.2/breeze-macros_2.11-0.11.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/rwl/jtransforms/2.4.0/jtransforms-2.4.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/spire-math/spire_2.11/0.7.4/spire_2.11-0.7.4.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/spire-math/spire-macros_2.11/0.7.4/spire-macros_2.11-0.7.4.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.4.1/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/jpmml/pmml-model/1.1.15/pmml-model-1.1.15.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/jpmml/pmml-agent/1.1.15/pmml-agent-1.1.15.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/jpmml/pmml-schema/1.1.15/pmml-schema-1.1.15.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.7/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.2.7/jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.7/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/spark-project/spark/unused/1.0.0/unused-1.0.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-core/1.1.0/smile-core-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-data/1.1.0/smile-data-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-math/1.1.0/smile-math-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-graph/1.1.0/smile-graph-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-scala_2.11/1.1.0/smile-scala_2.11-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-interpolation/1.1.0/smile-interpolation-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-nlp/1.1.0/smile-nlp-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/github/haifengl/smile-plot/1.1.0/smile-plot-1.1.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/swinglabs/swingx/1.6.1/swingx-1.6.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/jhlabs/filters/2.0.235/filters-2.0.235.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/swinglabs/swing-worker/1.1/swing-worker-1.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.8/xstream-1.4.8.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scalaj/scalaj-http_2.11/2.3.0/scalaj-http_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-scala_2.11/2.4.5/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.4.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.2/scala-reflect-2.11.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.5/jackson-core-2.4.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.5/jackson-annotations-2.4.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.5/jackson-databind-2.4.5.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.6/paranamer-2.6.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/15.0/guava-15.0.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/asm/asm-tree/3.2/asm-tree-3.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.10/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.19.0-GA/javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/2.0.1/annotations-2.0.1.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/com/novocode/junit-interface/0.11/junit-interface-0.11.jar:/home/builder/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/test-interface/1.0/test-interface-1.0.jar
last tree to typer: TypeTree(class Some)
tree position: line 12 of /home/builder/aaa/lll/featureSystem/src/test/scala/com/ppp/scratch/TypesTest.scala
tree tpe: Some[T]
symbol: (final case) class Some in package scala
symbol definition: final case class Some[+A] extends Option[A] with Product with Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
symbol package: scala
symbol owners: class Some
call site: trait TTBase in package <empty>
  == Source file context for tree position ==
  9     }
  10
  11     case class TTX[@specialized T](value:T) extends TTBase[T] {
  12       def evaluate:T = value
  13     }
  14
  15     println( TTX(123).evaluate )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is an unresolved bug [SI-7625](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7625) (and related [SI-8287](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8287)).